# How to pass parameter having space in executing batch script using createprocess in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I need to pass a parameter with space while executing below batch script using createprocess. Tried to give " for parameter alone but not working.

```
std::wstring setupDir =  L"\"D:\\Non Work\\New Bat File";
    std::wstring ExecutablePath =  L"\\Test.bat" ;
    std::wstring toolsSetupPath = L"";
    toolsSetupPath = L"CMD.exe /c " + setupDir +ExecutablePath +L"\" >C:\\AA 2.txt";
     DWORD commandLineLength = (DWORD)toolsSetupPath.size() + 1;
    LPWSTR process = (LPWSTR)_alloca(commandLineLength*sizeof(WCHAR));
    wcscpy_s(process,
             commandLineLength,
            toolsSetupPath.c_str());

    if (!CreateProcess(NULL, process, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT, env,NULL, &si, &pi))
    {
        std::cout << "FAILURE" << std::endl;
        std::cout << GetLastError();
        system("pause");
        abort();
    }
```

Comment: I don't think it's related to the space in the file name, you can't redirect stdout to a file with the `createProcess` argument string

Comment: try this: `+ ExecutablePath + L" >\"C:\\AA2.txt\"";` Otherwise, try inverting the path backward slashes to a forward ones. Need to know the cmd actually. Also use `wstringstream` to simply formulating the commandline.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is you have space in the argument and for this kind of argument should be enclosed by quotes.
So following particular line should solve the issue:

```
toolsSetupPath = L"CMD.exe /c " + setupDir + ExecutablePath + L"\" >\"C:\\AA 2.txt\"";
```

Comment: thanks @santosh I have a doubt. I created a bat which takes a parameter so calling that bat file with redirection eg: xx.bat &rty > "C:\test.txt" if I give & in parameter it's not writing to file else it's working fine.